# Scraping error in R package readHTMLTable: Error in make.names invalid multibyte string

Tags: html, r

I am trying to get some data from a HTML web by using readHTMLTable.

The web contains some Chinese utf-8 code, so it usually gives me some error.

First try:

```
u = "http://app.finance.ifeng.com/hq/stock_daily.php?code=sh600030"
url = htmlParse(u)
tbls = readHTMLTable(u,asText= TRUE)

dat <- data.frame(tbls)
```

ERROR:Error in make.names(vnames, unique = TRUE) : invalid multibyte string 5

Comment: `htmlParse` has an `encoding` parameter

Comment: @hrbrmstr,so how to resolve it?

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to add the argument `encoding = "UTF-8"`, in my case, to these functions or connections. More generally, providing the default encoding or a hook before parsing might be a more robust solution.

url = htmlParse(baseURL, encoding="GB2312")
table=readHTMLTable(url,header=,which=1,encoding="UTF-8")